# Can a check constraint relate to another table? Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have searched for solution to my problem and this [question describes it perfectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880698/can-a-check-constraint-relate-to-another-table).

> Let´s say I have one table called ProjectTimeSpan (which I haven´t, just as example!) containing the columns StartDate and EndDate.
>
> And that I have another table called SubProjectTimeSpan, also containing columns called StartDate and EndDate, where I would like to set a Check constraint that makes it impossible to set StartDate and EndDate to values "outside" the ProjectTimeSpan.StartDate to ProjectTimeSpan.EndDate
>
> Kind of a Check constraint that knows about another tables values...
> Is this possible?

But I have a hard time to implement the solution to oracle. I've got even more puzzled when other articles stated that check constraint can not relate to other tables.

Comment: check constraint can be implemented by function see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3880853/1867646 (sure the function complexity affects the performance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it can't.

A `FOREIGN KEY` constraint can (and must) relate to another table, but it can only perform equiality checks.

I.e. you can test that a column (or a set of columns) are equal to those in the other table but not more complex conditions (like inside a span or whatever).

You'll have to implement a trigger for that.

Comment: And beware that the trigger solution will have concurrency implications.