# SQL Server - Foreign Key Referencing Primary Key A OR B

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key-relationship

Say I have a table called Matchup that contains two sports teams.  I also have a table called Pick that has a column that must match either Team_A **OR** Team_B.  So it's a foreign key of one OR the other columns in Matchup.  Is this possible?

**Matchup**
Team_A
Team_B

**Pick**
Pick_Team - FK Matchup (Must match Team_A or Team_B from Matchup).

Comment: Add your comment (astanders answer) to the question body. Now its clear you should have a third table with all teams, right? And table Pick can then have a FK that targets that table's PK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would split your `Matchup` table into two: `Matchup` proper and `MatchupDetails`.

The `Matchup` table would have a `MatchupID` column as its primary key.

The `MatchupDetails` one would consist of at least two columns: `MatchupID` to reference the `Matchup` table and `TeamID` to reference the `Team` table (you do have one, don't you?). The two columns would form the table's composite primary key.

Finally, there would be this `Pick` table. Since you've got multiple users (as per one of your comments), there would need to be a `UserID` reference. Two more columns, `MatchupID` & `TeamID` would serve as a composite foreign key referencing the corresponding column set in `MatchupDetails`. And to ensure that one user can pick no more than one team from a match-up, a composite primary key of `(UserID, MatchupID)` should do.

To summarise, here's a complete outline of the relevant part of the schema:

- `Matchup`:

  ```
  MatchupID
  PRIMARY KEY (MatchupID)
  ```
- `MatchupDetails`:

  ```
  MatchupID
  TeamID
  FOREIGN KEY (MatchupID)
  FOREIGN KEY (TeamID)
  PRIMARY KEY (MatchupID, TeamID)
  ```
- `Pick`:

  ```
  UserID
  MatchupID
  TeamID
  FOREIGN KEY (UserID)
  FOREIGN KEY (MatchupID, TeamID)
  PRIMARY KEY (UserID, MatchupID)
  ```

Comment: Yes, I do have Team and User tables.  I believe that this, or some close variation, is what I am looking for.  Thanks!  (I'd up-vote the response but I don't have enough reputation yet...)

Comment: Ok I tried this out and it works great.  I was confused at first because the Matchup table in the example above only has an ID.  I added 'Matchup_Date' and 'Matchup_Venue' along with a few other columns and then it made perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that this is the correct approach.

I would rather recomend that you add an additional field to table Matchup (lets say Pick) and add a [CHECK CONSTRAINT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to ensure that it is either Team_A or Team_B.

> CHECK constraints enforce domain integrity by limiting the values that
>   are accepted by one or more columns. You can create a CHECK constraint
>   with any logical (Boolean) expression that returns TRUE or FALSE based
>   on the logical operators.

From [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> In a foreign key reference, a link is created between two tables when
>   the column or columns that hold the primary key value for one table
>   are referenced by the column or columns in another table. This column
>   becomes a foreign key in the second table.

And it does not seem to be what you are looking for.

Comment: This may be what i'm looking for.  To expand on the example, I have multiple users picking who is going to win that game, which is why I have it in a separate table.  Putting Picks in the same table as Matchup would defeat this.  Can a check constraint reference columns from a different table?

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880698/can-a-check-constraint-relate-to-another-table it seems like you can create a UDF which will accomplish what you need.