# How to create a check constraint SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some problem creating a check constraint on SQL server. 
Summarizing I have two tables: `employee` and `min_salary`

```
EMPLOYEE (
   SALARY DECIMAL
   . 
   . 
   . 
) 

MIN_SALARY (
   MIN_SALARY DECIMAL
)
```

I need to CHECK when insert a new Employee if the employee salary is greater than min_salary.

I have tried with functions and constraint check but i've not succeeded.

Comment: Have a try with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3880853/2451726)

Comment: It is far better to post what you did try and the errors you experienced. What you did post is not even tsql code and it appears that you have two tables - which complicates the logic.

Comment: @LuisQuijada . . . If you want to do this with a check constraint, you will need to add a helper function to get the minimum salary.  The alternative is to use a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but try this one.

```
 Select case when T0.Salary > T1.Min_Salary then 'Message here if greater than' else 'Message here if less than' end [Evaluation of salary] From Employee T0 Inner Join [dbo].[Min_Salary] T1 on T0.employeeId = T1.Id
```