# Django CheckConstraint: Elements of reverse ForeignKey lookup must not be empty

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, check-constraints, django-q

I've got these models:

```py
class Container(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                 check=~Q(elements=None),
                 name='container_must_have_elements'
            ),
        ]

class Element(models.Model):
    container = models.ForeignKey(Container),
        related_name='elements',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

I want to enforce the constraint that every `Container` object must have at least one `Element` referencing it via the foreign key relation.

As you can see I already added a check constraint. However, the negation operator `~` on the `Q` object seems to be forbidden. I get `django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: cannot use subquery in check constraint` when I try to apply the generated migration.

Without the negation operator the constraint seems to be valid (it only fails due to a data integrity error).

Is there another way I can express this constraint so it is supported by `CheckConstraint`?
(E.g. is there a way to check if the set of `elements` is not empty?)

Comment: Note that this constraint will generate a sort of circular dependency since you cannot create a `Container` without elements but in order to create an `Element` you need a container to reference. It seems to me that it makes no sense to have this constraint

Comment: Yes, you're right but the constraint can still be satisfied: The objects of both models must be created in a single database transaction.

Comment: @PeterF I'm not so sure about this single transaction. The Container still needs to be inserted into the db first in order to get a pk and only then can the Element be inserted. Won't the first insert raise an error then, i.e. are you sure constraints are checked only at the end of the transaction?

Comment: Enforcing the constraint immediately or only after transaction commit is both configurable: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-set-constraints.html

Comment: Here are approaches using SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880698/can-a-check-constraint-relate-to-another-table
They need to define a function in SQL. It seems defining a constraint on other tables is not possible solely using python code.

Comment: @PeterF since the constraint isn't checked in python anyway, you could just not use `CheckConstraint` in your model but set it in your migration using [`RunSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/migration-operations/#runsql)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll answer my own question by summarizing the question's comments.

A check constraint is intended to check every row in a table for a condition, which only takes the row itself into consideration and does not join other tables for this.

Sticking with SQL, one can formulate extended constraints including other tables by defining a function in SQL and calling it from within the constraint.

The `CheckConstraint` introduced in Django 2.2 only supports conditions on the table itself by using `Q` objects.

**Update**:

Since Django 3.1, `CheckConstraint`s not only support `Q` objects but also boolean `Expression`s. See the [Django 3.2 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/#check).

Comment: So is this possible at some way now?

Comment: @wowkin2 Sorry, I haven't tried if this constraint can be expressed via a `CheckConstraint` using an `Expression`. I fixed the broken link though. I hope it helps.
The constraint surely can be expressed in SQL.