# How to Limit One To Many Relationship Count In Entitiy Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have `Team` and `Player` tables. A team can have maximum of 6 players. This implemented in business logic. But if concurrent requests occurs teams might ended up with 7 players. What is correct way to avoid this in ef core.

Changing concurrency model only for this feels like overkill.

`HasCheckConstraint` promising but requires writing raw sql in efcore not feels like idiomatic. Also not sure about correct syntax. This gives

> 42703: column "Players" does not exist error.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Team>()
    .HasCheckConstraint("CK_Team_MaxPlayers", $"COUNT(\"Players\") <= 6");
```

Another solution implement transaction for every player add. But not sure about correct method.

```
await using var transaction =
    await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();

try
{
    var newPlayer = new TeamPlayer
    {
        UserId = user.Id,
    };
    
    team.Players.Add(newPlayer);
    await transaction.CommitAsync();
    
    //then what? check member count and rollback?
    //can i rollback committed transaction?
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // TODO: Handle failure
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, raw SQL is suitable for this purpose. | See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3880698/5045688 how to do this

Comment: Also, it can be implemented using a trigger.

Comment: If your database supports materialized/indexed views, you can create a view with a unique index enforcing the constraint. See https://spaghettidba.com/2011/08/03/enforcing-complex-constraints-with-indexed-views/ for some examples.