Enforcing two M2M relationships with FK with SQL Server
I have the following entities

**Account**
Id
Name



**User**
Id
Name


Users can belong to many accounts.
**AccountUser**
Id
Account_Id FK
User_Id Fk

Accounts can have many user groups.
**AccountUserGroup**
Id
Account_Id FK
Name

Users can be a member of an account's user group.
**AccountUserGroupMembership**
Id
User_Id FK
AccountUserGroup FK

How could I enforce that only users who belong to a AccountUserGroup be added to AccountUserGroupMembership for those accounts without business logic. Is this possible in SQL Server?
For example
User 1 belong to Account 100.
Account 200 has a AccountUserGroup, Id 1000.
AccountUserGroupMembership of User Id 1 AccountUserGroupId 200 would not be valid.
Thank you
I have FK constraints on all my tables so far
AccountUser - AccId and UserId
AccountUserGroup - AccId
AccountUserGroupMembership - AccUserGroupId and AccountUserId

Create a function and use it within your constraint. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880698/can-a-check-constraint-relate-to-another-table

That's easily done with composite keys. Composite keys can be used propagate relationships to a third table, not directly connected to the first one. In this case two different relationship path from the first table will get to the third one going through different "second tables".

Firstly, many-many join tables do not normally need a separate ID column. The primary key should just be a combination of the two foreign keys.
In answer to your question: you need to make AccountUserGroupMembership have a foreign key against AccountUserGroup, not against User or Account. And AccountUserGroup itself needs to have a key (can be a secondary unique key) containing the AccountId so that it can pass through.
CREATE TABLE AccountUser (
  User_Id int NOT NULL REFERENCES [User] (Id),
  Account_Id int NOT NULL REFERENCES Account (Id),
  PRIMARY KEY (User_Id, Account_Id)
);

CREATE TABLE AccountUserGroup (
  Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  Account_Id int NOT NULL REFERENCES Account (Id),
  Name varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  UNIQUE (Account_Id, Id)  -- extra key needed to apply the foreign key to it
);

CREATE TABLE AccountUserGroupMembership (
  AccountUserGroup_Id int NOT NULL,
  Account_Id int NOT NULL,
  User_Id int NOT NULL REFERENCES [User] (Id),
  PRIMARY KEY (Account_Id, AccountUserGroup_Id, User_Id),
  FOREIGN KEY (AccountUserGroup_Id, Account_Id) REFERENCES AccountUserGroup (Account_Id, Id)
);

This means that you can then only insert an AccountUserGroupMembership row where the pair of AccountUserGroup_Id, Account_Id is present in the AccountUserGroup table.
